# In Fig.$9.17.$ $PQRS$ and $ABRS$ are Parallelograms and $X$ is any point on side $BR$.

Tags: geometry

[image]In Fig.$9.17$ $PQRS$ and $ABRS$ are parallelograms and $X$ is any point on side $BR$. Show that 
i) $[PQRS]=[ABRS]$
ii)$[AXS]=1/2\cdot [PQRS]$

I have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe someone else can help with part (ii), but here's a hint for part (i):

Express the two areas you need to equate in terms of (1) the area of triangles $PAS$, (2) the area of triangle $QRS$, and (3) the area of parallelogram $AQRS$.  Notice what has to be true for the areas to be equal, and prove that.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for i):

Area of PQRS is the distance between lines PQ and RS times the length of RS.

Area of ABRS is the distance between lines AB and RS times the length of RS.